# Equilibrium in Game theory that does not hold the strategy of the other players constant

Tags: game-theory

Every time that one hears about Game Theory immediately after comes Nash equilibrium. Without doubt it has a remarkable significance. Nevertheless, I am more interested in other types of equilibrium, if they exist.

Does Game Theory consider equilibrium achieved without restricting other players strategies? I am thinking about the equilibrium in terms of the question posted [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Nash-equilibrium-and-saddle-point).

Comment: One might quibble and say they should be called solution concepts, not equilibrium, but there is Rationalizability, where player's beliefs about other's action don't need to be correct, just rational.  Then there is Dominance Solvable games,(either strictly or weakly) which don't require knowledge of the actions of the other players.  See Osborne and Rubinstein, Chapter 4.

Comment: I have read through it. It seems to be like condensing an evolutionary game in a single round. So then, should be better described as such?